# negative number of bytes reachable valgrind

Tags: function, memory-leaks, valgrind

While going through the sample code in valgrind which shows memeory leak cases I don't understand two things:

1. How can the number of bytes reachable or lost in any memory leak be
   in negative? What does it mean when the number of bytes is with a
   minus sign?
2. What is the need of an empty function `breakme()` with no
   statements? What purpose does it serve when it does nothing?

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../memcheck.h"
#include "leak.h"

char *b10;
char *b21;

char *b32_33[2];
static void breakme() {};
void f(void)
{
   int i;

   b10 = malloc (10);

   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details 10 bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_LEAK_CHECK;

   fprintf(stderr, "expecting to have NO details\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK;

   b10--; // lose b10
   b21 = malloc (21);
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details +10 bytes lost, +21 bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK;

   for (i = 0; i < 2; i ++)
      b32_33[i] = malloc (32+i);
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details +65 bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK;

   fprintf(stderr, "expecting to have NO details\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK;

   b10++;
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details +10 bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK;

   b10--;
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details -10 bytes reachable, +10 bytes lost\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_CHANGED_LEAK_CHECK;

   b10++;
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details -10 bytes lost, +10 bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_CHANGED_LEAK_CHECK;

   b32_33[0]--;
   fprintf(stderr, "expecting details 32 (+32) bytes lost, 33 (-32) bytes reachable\n"); fflush(stderr); breakme();
   VALGRIND_DO_CHANGED_LEAK_CHECK;

   fprintf(stderr, "finished\n");
}

int main(void)
{
   DECLARE_LEAK_COUNTERS;

   GET_INITIAL_LEAK_COUNTS;

   f();   // see leak-cases.c


   GET_FINAL_LEAK_COUNTS;

   PRINT_LEAK_COUNTS(stderr);

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A leak search can be done to show the "absolute numbers" of leaked memory.
Typically, such a leak search is done at the end of the run of your
program.
If you do several leak searches during your run, then a leak search
can (if you request it) show the "delta" of leaked memory compared
with the previous leak search.
Typically, these several leak searches are done via the Valgrind
embedded gdbserver (with GDB connected to it sending a monitor command),
or via  a client request such as VALGRIND_DO_ADDED_LEAK_CHECK
or in a shell (using vgdb to send a monitor command).

For such a delta leak search, you can show only the stack traces
which have an increase in the leaked memory, or show the stack traces
for which there is a change (increase or decrease).

For more information, see
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.monitor-commands
and
http://www.valgrind.org/docs/manual/mc-manual.html#mc-manual.clientreqs

The function breakme is there to make the automatic Valgrind regression
tests easier to do : a GDB is launched and puts a break inside function
breakme.
In Valgrind distribution, the perl script tests/vg_regtest.in is
the test driver, starting a Valgrind and optionally a second process
(which is GDB in the tests testing the Valgrind gdbserver).
For more details about this (and how the breakme function is used)
read tests/vg_regtest.in comments and gdbserver_tests/mcleak.*

Comment: ok Thank you. I got the answer to my first question that the negative number of bytes actually mean a decrease in number of bytes from a previous value of total bytes leaked or reachable. Can you explain a bit more about second question? Its not very clear how GDB is launched automatically and how will empty function make regression test easier? Regards

Comment: Edited the answer to give more details about Valgrind regtest